# Blender UV vertex limit

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have a small texture that I want to repeat over a big area. **100x100** times to be exact. To be able to do this, I edit the UVs for a plane, and try to extend them far beyond the image bounds. This works, though I can not manually enter values more than **10** for the UV vertices, when using normalized coordinates. I would like to enter **100** here, but that seems not to be possible. This is how it looks:

[image: UV limit]

My question is why this is the case, to have such a limit? Am I missing something, and can it be bypassed som how? I can actually scale the UVs beyond 10, but that is not very accurate. I am using **Blender 2.77**.

Comment: Please specify Blender Internal Render (BIR) or Cycles Render.  Both can repeat the texture in the UV coordinates.  The BIR has texture panel entries and Cycles can manipulate UV coordinates in nodes.  Both can do this with keyframes in case you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Blender Internal Render.  Material Texture Panel.

Size XY 8, 8.

[image]

Size XY 2, 2.

[image]

Size XY 1, 1. Mapping Extension Repeat. Default.

Adjust offset values to suit you.

[image]

The plane has a simple UV Unwrap.  UV Coordinates not further modified.